# empty flask sessions when running via gunicorn behind nginx

Tags: python, flask, cookies, gunicorn, nginx-reverse-proxy

If `flask` app running via `gunicorn` behind `nginx`, flask sessions does not work - meaning session object is empty at each request.

Here is `nginx` configuration

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    ssl_certificate         /etc/ssl/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key     /etc/ssl/key.pem;
    server_name  www.kanser.online;

    proxy_headers_hash_max_size 1024;
    proxy_headers_hash_bucket_size 128;

    location / {

        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass  http://unix:/root/hsctech/hsctech.sock;

        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Prefix /;

        proxy_set_header Cookie $http_cookie;
        proxy_cookie_path / /;
    }

}
```

Here is the code trying to use flask session via `flask-login`

```
@auth_view.route("/login", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    form = LoginForm(request.form)
    if request.method == "POST" and form.validate():
        if authenticate_user(form.username.data, form.password.data):
            flash("Logged in successfully.", "success")
            return redirect(location=url_for("views.admin.admin"))
        else:
            flash("Invalid username or password.", "error")
    try:
        return render_template("login.html", form=form)
    except TemplateNotFound:
        abort(404)
    except TemplateSyntaxError:
        abort(500)
```

Above code redirects to below code if login is successful.

```
@admin_view.route("/admin")
@login_required
def admin():
    try:
        return render_template("admin.html")
    except TemplateNotFound:
        abort(404)
    except TemplateSyntaxError:
        abort(500)
```

As `@login_required` decorator check `SecureSessionCookie` of Flask which is empty redirects even after successful login.

Requests are:

GET /login : initially open login page
POST /login : post username/password form
GET /ADMIN -> 302 Redirects to login

Finally this `systemctl` configuration is running `flask` via `gunicorn`.

```
[Unit]
Description=Gunicorn instance to serve Flask
After=network.target

[Service]
User=root
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/root/hsctech
Environment="PATH=/root/hsctech/.venv/bin"
ExecStart=/root/hsctech/.venv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:hsctec.sock -m 007 wsgi:app
```

Comment: first describe problem in question's body, not in question's title.

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: did you try to run without `try/except` and with `debug=True`  to see more usefull error message? Maybe it informs about some problem, or maybe it ask to create `secret key`?

Comment: I have of course tried debuggin so one important factor here that it is working when it is not behind a proxy. So from applications point of view there is no error as it just does not receive the cookies.
Because the error unfortunately being session empty so printing flask.session is <SecureCookieSession {}> this.  Which is not the case if it is not behind a proxy so I figured nginx is doing something with the cookies but none of the configuration parameters of nginx helped. @furas

Comment: you should mention it in question. It seems it is not problem with Python and maybe you should ask on similar portal `SeverFault`. There are questions like [reverse proxy - What is the difference between http\_cookie and cookie\_name in Nginx? - Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/872375/what-is-the-difference-between-http-cookie-and-cookie-name-in-nginx)